# How to paste a column of text in Notepad++ next to existing columns

Tags: notepad++

Basically what I want to do is as given below:

I have this text

```
text text2 text3 
text text2 text3 
text text2 text3 
text text2 text3 
text text2 text3 
text text2 text3 
text text2 text3 
text text2 text3
```

Now I have another column of text with the same number of rows, for example `text4`, which I want to paste to the right of the `text3` column.  So the final result should be like this:

```
text text2 text3 text4 
text text2 text3 text4 
text text2 text3 text4 
text text2 text3 text4 
text text2 text3 text4 
text text2 text3 text4 
text text2 text3 text4 
text text2 text3 text4
```

But when I try pasting, the column identities are lost and the new text wraps into the old text.  I am getting this:

```
text text2 text3 text4
text4
text4 
etc 
etc
```

I am marking all the way down until the last row and then pasting.

Comment: Replace `text3` to `text3 text4`?

Comment: Use column edit mode?

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcut to achieve your expectation.

- First copy *in column mode* the content  which you want to insert. (Here `text4`)
- Go to first line's **End**
- In keyboard, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> then also <kbd>⬇️</kbd> up to the required number of lines.
- To add space press <kbd>➡️</kbd> once (with out release the Shift + Alt)
- Now paste the copied content.

Sample execution in the GIF below:

> [image: Insert the text in the required place]

Comment: Needs to be copied also while in Column Mode (Alt+mouse) to work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Replace (CTRL+H)
2. Set "Search Mode" to "Regular Expression
3. In "Find what" field enter "$"
4. In "Replace with" enter the text you want on the right side of the line
5. Click "Replace all"

The "$" symbol in regular expressions is equivalent to the end of the line and along with the Replace function can be used to "add" something to the end of the line.